# Executing dynamic sql code with sp_executesql with return value

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

I'm looking for a way to execute the @batchSQL dynamic SQL through sp_executesql. I'm working on synchronizing tables between two databases and due to poor performance trying to see if synchronizing data in batches could help solve the performance issues.

The batching part is just an excerpt, but it would execute all stored procedures that synchronize data by starting with the first record in a table and calculating the next batch size based on how many records it can synchronize within one minute.

There is a default set for the first run: 10 for @batchSize and 0 for @batchRow. The calculations are not really relevant to the issue so I've left that part out and just kept the important bits. In the @batchSQL variable the @batchProcess contains the name of the next stored procedure to run.

In order to run the second batching process after the first 'default' run, the @cursRows variable gets the number of rows in the cursor with @@CURSOR_ROWS. This way the second batch process will start from the first record not yet synchronized. However after the sp_executesql line runs, the value returned is null in the BatchSize column of the BatchTable table.

When I'm not executing it as dynamic sql but hardcoding the @batchSQL line with the same values as used in the default run, it returns the value from @cursRows correctly.

```
DECLARE 
        @batchRow int, -- First row number included in batch
        @batchSize int, -- Calculated batch size
        @batchProcess nvarchar(100), -- Batch process name (stored procedure)
        @batchSql nvarchar(max); -- Batch execution statement
        @cursRowsOUT int, -- Number of rows loaded into the procedure cursor
        @cursRows int, -- Number of rows loaded into the procedure cursor

SELECT @batchSize = 10, @batchRow = 0, @batchProcess = 'SYNCHRONIZE_ALL_CARS';

SELECT @batchSQL = concat(N'DECLARE @cursRows int EXEC [dbo].[', @batchProcess, N'] @batchRow= ', @batchRow, N', @batchSize= ', @batchSize, N', @cursRows = @cursRows OUTPUT');

EXEC sp_executesql @batchSQL, N'@cursRowsOUT int', @cursRowsOUT = @cursRows;

SET [dbo].[BatchTable] SET BatchSize = @cursRowsOUT
```

Here is the procedure that I'm testing with called by the previous code snippet.

```
ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[SYNCHRONIZE_ALL_CARS]
    @batchRow int, 
    @batchSize int,
    @cursRows int OUTPUT
AS
BEGIN
    SET NOCOUNT ON;

    DECLARE
        @carId nvarchar(15),
        @manufacturer nvarchar(50),
        @type nvarchar(50);

    DECLARE sync_cursor CURSOR STATIC FOR
        SELECT CAR_ID, MANUFACTURER, TYPE
        FROM [TestData].[dbo].[CAR]
        ORDER BY (SELECT NULL)
        OFFSET @batchRow ROWS
        FETCH NEXT @batchSize ROWS ONLY;

    OPEN sync_cursor;

    SET @cursRows = @@CURSOR_ROWS;

    FETCH NEXT FROM sync_cursor INTO
        @carId,
        @manufacturer,
        @type;

    WHILE @@FETCH_STATUS = 0
        BEGIN
            EXEC [dbo].[SYNCHRONIZE_CAR]
                @carIdentifier = @carId,
                @manufacturerName = @manufacturer,
                @typeName = @type;

            FETCH NEXT FROM sync_cursor INTO
                @carId,
                @manufacturer,
                @type;
        END
    CLOSE sync_cursor;
    DEALLOCATE sync_cursor;
END
```

Does anyone have an idea how to get @cursRows back from this query?

All help is greatly appreciated!

Comment: FYI `N'[', @batchProcess, N']` is **not** injection safe. If you want to safely inject object names, use `QUOTENAME`.

Comment: Seems like, however, you just need to define `@cursRowsOUT` as an `OUTPUT` parameter. You do it in the dynamic statement already, so you should understand how to do this.

Comment: I have removed your [[tag:batch-file]] tag, as this does not appear to be related to a Windows, DOS, or OS/2 batch script with a `.bat` or `.cmd` extension. Please make sure that you read the descriptions for your tags before assigning them.

Comment: If you were doing this as a set-based operation, you probably wouldn't need batching in the first place. Why have you got cursors? To top it off, you are querying the full table every time when you use `OFFSET FETCH`

Comment: @Larnu The parameters are generated, not an input to the procedure, so injection is not really possible.

If this is what you mean with defining `@cursRowsOut` as an `OUTPUT` parameter, then I tried it but I still get null value back.
`EXEC sp_executesql @batchSQL, N'@cursRowsOUT int OUTPUT', @cursRowsOUT = @cursRows;`

Comment: @MártonKovács,  you didn't define `@cursRowsOUT` as an `OUTPUT` parameter though... `EXEC sp_executesql @batchSQL, N'@cursRowsOUT int OUTPUT', @cursRowsOUT = @cursRows OUTPUT;`

Comment: @Charlieface I'm not doing this as a set-based operation for a reason. Yes, the full table is queried each time, since the table is not indexed. Changing this wouldn't help much with the performance issues either since the issue is on the receiving database (where I only have read access) and not on the querying database.

Comment: @Larnu You're right, but I've tried that as well. Sadly, it's still a null value.

Comment: That would mean that the value within the dynamic SQL is `NULL` too then. Take this simple [example](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=8962190fad1136dd9fd6bc6709b15bdd).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your dynamic SQL is not quite right, because you are not passing back the value in an `OUTPUT` parameter, you are just dumping it into a local variable.

**But you actually don't need dynamic SQL here at all.** You can directly call a stored procedure whose name is stored in a variable

```sql
SELECT @batchSize = 10, @batchRow = 0, @batchProcess = 'dbo.[SYNCHRONIZE_ALL_CARS]';

EXEC @batchProcess
  @batchRow = @batchRow,
  @batchSize = @batchSize,
  @cursRows = @cursRows OUTPUT;
```

If you *really* wanted to use dynamic SQL, you could do it like this (note that the parameters are passed right through rather than injected)

```sql
SELECT @batchSQL = N'
EXEC [dbo].' + QUOTENAME(@batchProcess) + N'
  @batchRow = @batchRow,
  @batchSize = @batchSize,
  @cursRows = @cursRows OUTPUT;
';

EXEC sp_executesql @batchSQL,
  N'@cursRows int',
  @cursRows = @cursRows;
```